# How to determine if a column exists in SQL server DB in other tables with a different name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to fetch specific hardware data from source tables. The hardware information is present in a table Server_Data with columns as follows,

```
          Server_ID, Server Property, Property_Value
               65          Model          Cisco 123
               65          Name           Cisco abc
```

I need to link this table with System table that has columns as follows,

```
           System_ID,   System_IP
                 1      10.20.30.40
```

I searched all tables in database but Server_ID column is present only in Server _Data table. Also, I searched all tables if there exists a table that links System_ID with Server_ID, but there is no such table.

I need to find if the Server_ID column is present in any other table with some other name (say Server_Key or just Key). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There really isn't any special tricks, you can try to find by name from sys.columns, and try to limit it with data type

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks for the comment. Is there a way to check if data in Server_ID column is being fetched or pulled from some other table ? I need to find the root from where this data is being pulled to Server_ID.

Comment: I think you'll have to scan the sources (stored procedures + whatever else you're using), most likely things like that are done in either SQL or other code outside the database.

Answer (score 0):

Only using SQL, there will not be a way to find an identical column in another table, especially if it has a different name.  I think you would need to manually compare every column in every other table to that column to find a match.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would start by running the following SP:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'Server_Data'
```

That will tell you if the Server_ID column is referencing any other table in the DB or not.